# Child Route with Parent Route Path Parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following:

```
<Route path="things/:id" component={...}>
  <Route path="thing-types" component={…} />
</Route>
```

When I build the `<Link to="thing-types">` I end up with `/things/thing-types` instead of `things/100/thing-types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `<Link>` isn't as smart as I thought it was. I had to modify to:

```
<Link to={`/things/${thing.id}/thing-types`}>Thing Types</Link>
```